# ImportError: cannot import name 'accuracy' from 'torch_geometric.utils'

Tags: python, pytorch

my code：

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch_geometric.nn.conv.gcn_conv import gcn_norm
from torch_geometric.utils import accuracy as accuracy_1d
```

my pytorch version is 1.11.0, and cuda version is 11.5.2

the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonProject\LPGNN\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from models import NodeClassifier
  File "D:\pythonProject\LPGNN\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from torch_geometric.utils import accuracy as accuracy_1d
ImportError: cannot import name 'accuracy' from 'torch_geometric.utils' (D:\Anaconda\envs\LPGNN\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\utils\__init__.py)
```

how to solve?

I read the "D:\Anaconda\envs\LPGNN\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\utils_*init*_.py", but there is no "accuracy" in it.

Comment: There is no `accuracy` module under torch_geometric.utils. See here:

https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html

Answer (score 0):

I found my torch_geometric version is 2.4.0, "accuracy" only exists in versions less than or equal to 2.0.4